# How to post input data from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

View

```
@page
@model modal.PagesModal
<form method="post">
        <label for="date">Date</label>
         <input asp-for="datefield" class="date" id="date" type="text"/>
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" data-toggle="datepicker" data-target-name="date">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </button>
         </span>
         <div >
            <button class="btn refreshButton">Refresh</button>
         </div>
</form>
```

Model

```
 public class PagesModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string datefield { get; set; }
        public List<> result{get;set} = new List<>();
        public PagesModel(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
            result = GetPagesFromDB(datefield);
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void onPost(){
    result = GetPagesFromDB(datefield);
}
```

I want to get the datefield (input asp-for="datefield"...) from my view
and post it to controller to get database values accordingly.

The problem is that datefield value is NULL when posted to controller. I cannot figure out why exactly the datefield value is not taken by controller.
I have searched a lot but could not find the reason.

Comment: Your code looks fine and should work. Can you share your Post method ?

Comment: But then why is datefield value null. GetpagesFromDB() method returns nothing because datefield comes out to be null

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code and tested locally and datefield is not null for me.

Comment: You need to share more content. You need to explicitly refer the action in your form, because the server doesn't know what to do:
<form method="post" action="onPost">

Comment: Another thing you have to do is to get the calendar value from the client and send it to the server, because you are selecting a value from the interface but your aren't giving it a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You're not accepting anything in `OnPost`. What you should have is:

```
public void OnPost(PagesModel model) {
```

Since you're not accepting the model on post, it's just providing a default instance, which has `null` for the `datefield`.

Comment: Nope. You're totally wrong here. `OnPost` doesn't need to have the page model as parameter. The posted data depends on the properties decorated with 
`[BindProperty]` attribute.

Comment: I did not know how to use OnPost() method. But now I figured it out. I had to use ViewData["day"] = Request.Form["date"];  to get the string from the view. Thank you all for help.